# vms fortran read/write unit designation

Tags: fortran, fortran77, vms, vax

I have been tasked with porting some old (circa 1986) VAX VMS FORTRAN code to c++ and have run into a bit of a stumbling block.  The following two lines of code are part of a computed goto.

```
WRITE(2'N) (Y (I), I = 1, 5)
READ(2'N, ERR = 48) (Y (I), I = 1, 5)
```

My problem is the unit designator "2'N" , if that is indeed what it is. "N" is an integer variable passed in to the subroutine.  I've done quite a bit of googleing for this pattern and reading what VMS documentation I could find, but have been unable to locate any info with respect to this pattern with the apostrophe.  I understand the implied do loop that follows the write and read statements, but I don't understand 'where' this is writing to and reading from.  Browsing the rest of the FORTRAN code doesn't reveal a unit=2 open statement that could be associated with this call, so it seems likely it's not a disk file, but I'm not certain.  I'm hoping someone here can reach back into their memory and help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read the [VMS VAX FORTRAN manual](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/dec/vax/lang/fortran/AA-D034E-TE_VAX_FORTRAN_Language_Reference_Manual_Jun88.pdf) correctly, `'N` specifies the `N`-th record in unit `2`. 
From Cl. 7.1.1.6 "Record Specifier":

> The record specifier identifies the number of the record you wish to access in a file with relative organization. It takes either one of the following forms:
>
> ```
> REC = r
> 'r
> ```
>
> ***r*** 
>   Is a numeric expression with a value that represents the position in a direct access file of the record to be accessed. [...]

**Please note** that this is not Standard-conforming Fortran! Most compilers will not accept this syntax. Instead, use `REC=...`:

```
WRITE(2, REC=N) (Y (I), I = 1, 5)
READ(2, REC=N, ERR = 48) (Y (I), I = 1, 5)
```

---

The file at unit `2` needs not be open explicitly. This is specified in the same document, Cl. 7.1.1.2 "Logical Unit Specifier":

> A logical unit number is assigned to a file or device in one of the two ways:
>
> - Explicitly trough an OPEN statement [...]
> - Implicitly by the system [...]

In the latter case, the file name used is defined in [Cl. 4.2.2.1 "FORTRAN Logical Names" of the VAX Fortran user manual](http://odl.sysworks.biz/disk$cddoc04sep11/decw$book/d3yvaa17.p136.decw$book):

> VAX FORTRAN provides predefined logical names in the
>   following form:
>
> ```
> FOR0nn[.DAT]
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>    WRITE (17,200)
> ```
>
> If you enter the preceding statement without including an
>      explicit file specification, the data is written to a file named
>      FOR017.DAT on your default disk under your default
>       directory.

Most modern compilers will create a file `fort.nn` in this case.

Comment: Thank you for this! It makes much more sense now. Thanks also for the links to the manual.  There is one spot in the code that does open a file explicitly as unit4, "ELIBn.DAT", and the file directory location has those files numbered 1 thru 9.  I can figure out the rest from here.